# Index and length must refer to a location within the string rand number

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to pass a random number to a character generator that will then return a random string with the length passed to it.

The StringToByteArray is as follows:

```
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

If I pass a number manually to it like so:

```
byte[] strarr = Program.StringToByteArray(Program.GetUniqueKey(25));
```

It will work correctly and pass back a random string 25 chars long.

If I however pass a random number to it, it will pass the error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string"

```
int rndn = rnd.Next(20, 40);
byte[] strarr = Program.StringToByteArray(Program.GetUniqueKey(rndn));
```

What would be causing this?

GetUniqueKey:

```
public static string GetUniqueKey(int maxSize)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[304];
            chars =
            *long list of chars*
            byte[] data = new byte[1];
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
                data = new byte[maxSize];
                crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
            }
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
            foreach (byte b in data)
            {
                result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: What does `Program.GetUniqueKey` do? Can you show it?

Comment: Are you asking what will cause it to work correctly?  Your title would seem to indicate an error but the question never gets there

Comment: Some of the post didn't get added, edited it in.

Comment: Added GetUniqueKey function also

Comment: And what keeps you from debugging it and at least point to the line with problem and what were the inputs?

Comment: `StringToByteArray` only works for strings that have even length, I think that your problem is that you are passing to it a string of an odd length

Comment: Are you sure that it works for length 25?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. 24 works but 25 doesn't, what would be the easiest fix?

Comment: I imagine something along the lines of "2 * rnd.Next(70 / 2, 130 / 2)" would work

Comment: If you use even numbers, it would work. Do you care about whether your strings have odd or even lengths?

Comment: No, they shouldn't matter.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason why you are not using the result of `GetNonZeroBytes` immediately (as a random byte array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringToByteArray` converts a hexadecimal string into an array of bytes.

Hexadecimal strings must have a length that is even because each byte is presented by two characters.

Here is what you can do to make sure that your random number is even:

```
int rndn = rnd.Next(10, 20) * 2;
```

This line is a replacement for:

```
int rndn = rnd.Next(20, 40);
```